# what is the use of comparator inside numpy array selector

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code I am trying to understand.

```
BigX = np.load('./soybean_samples.npz') ##order W(52*6) S(100) P(14) S_extra(4)
X = BigX['data']
print(X)
X_tr = X[X[:, 1] <= 2017]
```

I don't understand the purpose of

```
<= 2017
```

what is this kind of array value selection called and what exactly is the code doing?

Comment: Examine `X[:, 1] <= 2017` by itself first.

Answer (score 1):

It means get all rows in X whose 2nd( 1 in column index) column's values are <= 2017.

Its called [`Boolean Indexing`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your data, but isn't this just a simple column filter, probably for filtering the year of samples?